# Is there a way to queue an update of a spreadsheet on offline Google Sheets so that it waits until the device (Android tablet) is online?

Tags: android, google-sheets, web-applications, synchronization, offline

Here is the context:
I'm on an FRC team and we're trying to digitize our scouting system. As of now, we're using an a web app that generates QR codes based on a form and we intend to scan these using another tablet. The catch is that none of the tablets have internet access during the competition, so we can't update the Sheet immediately. Is there some way to make a change to an offline Google Sheet that is stored on the device so that it syncs automatically when it has WiFi later?

As of now, I have a working system to read QR codes on a laptop, and can easily port that to an Android app, and I've also tried the Google Sheets API (which doesn't work for obvious reasons), so now I'm looking for a good offline solution that can sync online later. We're thinking that updating the offline Google Sheet would be the simplest option, but I can't seem to find any resources on this topic online so I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no (simple) way to do this. Google Sheet files only exist online. Even the `.gsheet` files that you can usually see if you're syncing to your computer with [Drive for Desktop](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/13022292) are just shortcuts to the web that do not store any actual data. Everything is stored in Google's Cloud.

There is an ["offline mode"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102) for Sheets that allows you to work offline on your files and the updates are synced when you connect to the internet. The problem is that this requires you to use Google Chrome with the offline Docs [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-offline/ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi). This works essentially by having Chrome hold the Sheet's data until it can be synced, it's not an actual file on your computer. Now, I'm not an expert on this, but it may be possible to simulate Chrome as a [headless browser](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/) and work offline this way, but it seems that you'd have to interact directly with the DOM or simulate a mouse to input the data, which would be very difficult.

I believe the easiest workaround would be to just create a CSV, Excel or OpenDocument Spreadsheet file on your tablets, then later use the Drive API [`files.update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update) to convert these files and overwrite a Google Sheets file with their data. Google has a [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads) on how to do this. Note that this overwrites the entire file with your new data.

If need more control over specific cells rather than overwriting the Sheet you could follow the same principle to create a simple CSV file on your tablets and then do something like adding new rows with the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) to your online file. The best option will depend on your use case, but you won't be able to just create offline Sheets files, so you should try to figure out a strategy to use a different offline format and then import it to Sheets with one of the above methods.

##### References:

- [Uploading to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)
- [Working with the Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)